# Como faço para saber se pelo menos um elemento de uma lista está contido em outra lista?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Eu tenho duas listas:

```
var lista01 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var lista02 = new List<int> { 7, 7, 7, 7, 7 };
```

Eu preciso verificar se pelo menos um elemento da lista 1 existe na lista 2, então o resultado para o exemplo acima deve ser falso.

Mas se minha lista for:

```
var lista01 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var lista02 = new List<int> { 5, 7, 7, 7, 7 };
```

Eu quero que o resultado seja verdadeiro.

Como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existem alguns métodos em linq que podem te ajudar a fazer isto:

#### [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Se o resultado de uma interseção resultar em 1 ou mais elementos significa que pelo menos um é igual.

```cs
var resultado = lista01.Intersect(lista02);
bool existeElementoIgual = resultado.Any();
```

Recomendo o uso deste método.

É possível passar um `IEqualityComparer<T>` como segundo parâmetro caso seja necessário comparar objetos mais complexos.

#### [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Se o resultado de uma exclusão conter menos elementos que o total significa que pelo menos um elemento é igual.

```cs
var resultado = lista01.Except(lista02);
bool existeElementoIgual = resultado.Count() != lista01.Count;
```

É possível passar um `IEqualityComparer<T>` como segundo parâmetro caso seja necessário comparar objetos mais complexos.

#### [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Se qualquer elemento da lista 1 for igual a qualquer elemento da lista 2 significa que há um elemento igual.

```cs
bool existeElementoIgual = lista01.Any(e => lista02.Any(o => o == e));
```

#### [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) e [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Se qualquer elemento da lista 1 for encontrado na lista 2 significa que há um elemento igual.

```cs
bool existeElementoIgual = lista01.Any(e => lista02.IndexOf(e) != -1);
```

A desvantagem do `IndexOf` é que impossibilita a comparação de objetos a partir de uma propriedade qualquer *inline*, pois ele utiliza `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`.

---

#### Performance

Em uma lista grande, `lista01.Any(e => lista02.Any(o => o == e))` terá uma performance muito boa **somente** caso o valor contido na segunda lista esteja no inicio da primeira lista. Caso contrario este método será extremamente lento, pois ele percorre a lista 1 sequencialmente e para cada objeto da lista 1 ele percorre a lista 2 sequencialmente.

Em um teste de performance obtive os seguintes resultados:

Listas com 5 elementos cada, teste 10000000 vezes.

```
Intersect     : 00:00:02.9260135
Except        : 00:00:03.4404527
AnyAny        : 00:00:06.5709693
AnyIndexOf    : 00:00:01.9882278
```

Listas com 100000 elementos cada, teste 500 vezes. Elemento da terceira posição da lista01 é igual ao último elemento da lista02.

```
Intersect     : 00:00:02.4397784
Except        : 00:00:04.2595364
AnyAny        : 00:00:02.9761128
AnyIndexOf    : 00:00:00.0919344
```

Listas com 100000 elementos cada, teste 500 vezes. Último elemento da lista01 é igual ao último elemento da lista02.

```
Intersect     : 00:00:02.4927969
Except        : 00:00:04.2668677
AnyAny        : mais de um minuto e teste encerrado
AnyIndexOf    : mais de um minuto e teste encerrado
```